# Can cooper pairs form in the absence of any external magnetic field?

Tags: superconductivity

Let us cool a superconductor below its critical T in the absence of any external magnetic field. No electric current will flow. Though there is no current, are there cooper pairs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are consequences to superconductivity even with no
current imposed.   In particular, a superconducting material has
anomalously low thermal conductivity (in consequence of the
electrons not coupling to lattice phonons), which implies there
are Cooper pairs formed.

As a practical matter, it is unclear if one can make a true
zero of magnetic field, though it would be very useful if (rather
than just low field) total nullification were possible.  Moving
superconductor shields can create a good approximation of zero
B field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are. A superconductor can have zero current.